# Why is it that when I resize my select the first element becomes selected?

Tags: javascript, html

If the `size` of a `<select>` tag is dynamically changed from JavaScript, the first element becomes automatically selected if the initial `size` attribute was either `0` or `1` (MSEdge, Win10).

```html
<select id="s" size="1">
  <option>a
  <option>b
  <option>c
</select>

<select size="3">
  <option>a
  <option>b
  <option>c
</select>

<script>
s.size=3;
</script>
```

I imagine a `size` of 0 or 1 forces a selection, but I can't see why this is, as I didn't ask it to.

Does anyone have an explanation?

Comment: @Liam; when `size=1` nothing is selected by default, it only happens on a resize.

Comment: @Liam; I don't want to be able to see it. I have solved it with either `size=20` initially or `s.selectedIndex=-1`, but I don't like either solution. Your `multiple` solution allows for multiple selections, which I don't want either.

Comment: You've not asked for a "solution", you've asked for an explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually covered in the [specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#attr-select-size):

> If nodes are inserted or nodes are removed causing the list of options
> to gain or lose one or more option elements, or if an option element
> in the list of options asks for a reset, then, if the select element's
> multiple attribute is absent, the user agent must run the first
> applicable set of steps from the following list:
>
> - If the select element's display size is 1, and no option elements in    the select element's list of options have their selectedness set
>   to    true
>
>   - **Set the selectedness of the first option element in the list of       options in tree order that is not disabled, if any, to true.**
> - If two or more option elements in the select element's list of    options have their selectedness set to true
>
>   - Set the selectedness of    all but the last option element with its    selectedness set to true in    the list of options in tree
>     order to    false.

Comment: This doesn't explain the logic behind the course of action.

Comment: What does that mean? Your question was "Does anyone have an explanation?". This is the explanation. If that's NOT your question. Please edit your question

Comment: @JMP That is not the job of a specification.